# Running Cucumber Test cases in parallel

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, sbt, cucumber

I am using **Cucumber + Scala + SBT**. I would like to parallelize cucumber scenarios.

Unless I am missing something here,

- Cucumber does not support parallel execution.
- Maven has capability to invoke scenarios in parallel. What about SBT ?
- Some customs plugins can do this.

What is the best practise or the most recommandable plugin ?

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Have you tried setting `fork in Test := true`? This might be enough.

Comment: Nothing has changed :/

Comment: Can you please explain how you have set up to run Cucumber tests from sbt? Trying to do this now, and there is not a lot of documentation